# code to force email fail to be delivered

Tags: html, email

I need a code example which can be added in the html panel of the email body. the code must force the delivery of the email to fail, and my microsoft server mail server shall send me a delivery fail email notification.

Or i can also use a code which send a feed with the mail address i just send to my inbox.
Does anybody knows what code i can put in the email to achieve that?

Comment: Is this even possible?

Comment: How is this supposed to work, given that the delivery must already have taken place once the HTML can be read? What is the real world situation that you need this for?

Comment: i know javascript can make email to fail. but i do not know what java code i should put there

Comment: Wouldn't some form of email header change be necessary? That's if one exists...

Comment: Does my answer answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no method of doing this. It is up to the email server that you have chosen to send the email - if they don't send it, they may not tell you. No code will change this.